# How to parse a weirdly formatted data file?

Tags: csv

How to read a weirdly formatted data file?

For example if there are different types of seperators (, : |) all used together?

Looking at a dataframe example, something along these lines: 
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the source of this monstrosity?

Comment: Some government data table or other, I'd bet!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Incompetence. It's a decent sized private organisation. The person/people who implemented this format clearly did not understand data analytics.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get out of having to write a custom parser here.

Comment: monstrous evils such as this are not uncommon on the not for profit private sector. and in hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monstrous response to the monstrous data. First, split each column containing k:v pairs and convert them to pandas Series. Combine the results for all three "Other" columns into one dataframe:

```
others = pd.concat(data[x].str.split(':').apply(pd.Series) 
                   for x in ('Other1', 'Other2', 'Other3')).dropna(how='all')

#                  0                  1
#0          Hospital   Awesome Hospital
#1           Hobbies            Cooking
#2          Hospital   Awesome Hospital
#0       Maiden Name              Rubin
#1  Hobby Experience           10 years
#2       Maiden Name            Simpson
#0               DOB         2015/04/09
#2               DOB         2015/04/16
```

Do some index manipulations (we want the keys to become column names):

```
others = others.reset_index().set_index(['index',0]).unstack()
#                 1                                                          
#0              DOB   Hobbies Hobby Experience           Hospital Maiden Name
#index                                                                       
#0       2015/04/09      None             None   Awesome Hospital       Rubin
#1             None   Cooking         10 years               None        None
#2       2015/04/16      None             None   Awesome Hospital     Simpson
```

Remove the hierarchical column index produced by `unstack()`:

```
others.columns = others.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Put the pieces together again:

```
pd.concat([data[["Full Name","Town"]], others], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

[`parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) has a nice interface and might be good option for pulling data such as this out:

```
>>> import parse
>>> format_spec='{}: {}' 
>>> string='Hobbies: Cooking'
>>> parse.parse(format_spec, string).fixed
('Hobbies', 'Cooking')
```

Use `compile` if you will parse the same spec over and over:

```
>>> other_parser = parse.compile(format_spec)
>>> other_parser.parse(string).fixed
('Hobbies', 'Cooking')
>>> other_parser.parse('Maiden Name: Rubin').fixed
('Maiden Name', 'Rubin')
```

The `fixed` property returns the parsed arguments as a tuple. Using these tuples we can just create a bunch of dictionaries, feed them into `pd.DataFrame`, and merge with the first df:

```
import parse
import pandas as pd

# slice first two columns from original dataframe
first_df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='t').ix[:,0:2]

# make the parser
other_parser = parse.compile('{}: {}')

# parse remaining columns to a new dataframe
with open(filepath) as f:
    # a generator of dict objects is fed into DataFrame
    # the dict keys are column names
    others_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(other_parser.parse(substr).fixed for substr in line.split('\t')[2:]) for line in f)

# merge on the indexes
df = pd.merge(first_df, others_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```